# Cylinder becomes deformed at corners with curve modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, scale

I'm trying to use a rectangle converted into a curve, used with a scaled down cylinder combined with an array modifier to use as decorative trim around some woodwork but the cylinder becomes deformed pinches inward around the corners. Is [image]there a way for me to compensate for the deformation and maintain the scale around the entire modified curve?.

Comment: A simple bevel will not do for this particular application as the trims shape is cylindrical in shape and not beveled. It's shape is like rope or a candy cane without the bend.

Comment: I know i could slice it at a 45 degree angle at the corners but how do i do that lol. sorry new to blender like just over a week new lol.

Comment: File was uploaded it's Example_file.blend not sure if worked as i have never shared a blend file before.

Comment: show an image of what you are trying to model

Comment: you need to put the address of this page in the field, then upload, then share the link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131793/how-do-i-create-a-nice-miter-joint-between-these-two-pieces/131899#131899 .. make your path curve **2D**, and use either a home-made profile, or for a simple circle, the curve's native bevel, with a reasonable resolution.

Answer (score 1):

**!!! Check out my other Answer which avoids using the curve modifier.**

If you don't want a curved look at the corners but you have to use the curve modifier then you might do this:

Since the curve modifier tries to displace vertices along the curve you need some more vertices so the deformation can be closer to the real shape of the curve. So a simple solve would be to add some loop cuts to your rope or do the detail modeling of the rope first (because then the rope will probably have many more vertices anyway).

Also for the modelling part of the rope-like ornamentation maybe have a look at the rope-modeling answer by @Robin Betts:
[How to make a rope curving in a certain way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146396/how-to-make-a-rope-curving-in-a-certain-way#comment249832_146396)

Happy Blending! :)

Comment: Thanks for the ref :D.. but in this case, since it's woodwork, I think @Mingo is probably looking for a [miter](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/131899/35559).. unfortunately, if the molding doesn't lie in a plane, Blender isn't clever enough to do Japanese joinery for you... yet... but here, I think we're OK.

Comment: Robin is correct i'm looking for a miter at the corners and the object is planar, It's just a plane extruded just enough for a little depth with loop cuts and extrusions to have that hershey bar woodwork look. I have a question how do i share more than one picture?. It seems i can only share one picture per question but yet someone answered my question with numerous pics a few days ago. As of right now i only know how to add new pictures to an existing post is to answer om own question lol.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against trying to use a curve modifier for making the corners.

Since you specified in the comments that:

> It's shape is like rope or a candy cane without the bend

A plausible approach might be something like this:

[image]

1. Assuming you have a starting geometry as seen in 1.
2. You then use a 45deg rotated cube with a boolean modifier to make
   a nice cut.
3. Then you apply the boolean modifier and delete the cube
4. Then you can use a mirror modifier and an aligned empty (cursor to
   selected and then object to cursor etc.) to make 4.
5. Now depending on how your mesh in 1. repeats (symmetric or
   antisymmetric) you either use the mirror modifier or some rotational
   steps to achieve 5.

---

However if you only want to do this for a cylinder then it might be easier to use the shear tool (use a value of 1 for the standard cylinder), then extrude along a specific axis and then scale the new face to 0 along that axis. Finally use the mirror modifier to make the whole frame:

[image]

Comment: OMG! thank you so much that's exactly the effect i'm looking for. Thanks to all of you for taking the time to to review and consult my situation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Still learning to navigate this website and i'm not sure how to share a blender file yet :/ to the website. But i just need the curve to not deform my cylinder at the corners when using an array

Comment: To answer some of the forum related questions: You can edit you original question to include all of the additional info you posted here. You can add multiple images to a question, just like you added the first image. It should then be added at the current cursor location (Use .jpg pictures, otherwise the file size may be too large for that). And to upload a .blend file just upload the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ which generates a link which you then simply copy and paste into your question here.